# can anybody tell me how to find alphanumeric in a string using regex in python the string would be "123 Akshay 123 1A1 123" i want only 1A1

Tags: python

```
import re
S = "123 1331A1 Keshav 111a "
a = re.search("\w*[^ ]\d[^ ]*\w*[^ ]*", S).group()
print(a)
```

Output was `123`, but expected `1331A1 111a`

Comment: And what are the rules to find the part you want? BTW, you provided two different strings in the subject of the question and in your code.

Comment: Refer the [markdown guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how you should post code snippets, please do not type code as regular text with no spacing.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not necessary to use regex, you can do it this way too:

```
words = S.split()
alnumWords = filter(lambda s: isalnum(s), words)
```

This uses the [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function, that selects those elements of a list that meet a predicate function.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re` module you can do something like this:

```
import re
a = "123 1331A1 Keshav 111a "
output = re.findall(r'(\d+[a-zA-Z]\d?)', a)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
['1331A1', '111a']
```

Comment: i don't want the regex only for this solution i want to fetch all type of alphanumeric words and its doesn't depends on the size and when i am putting  [\w\d]+[a-zA-Z]\d? its takes all the starting alphabets.

Comment: @AkshayBansal Use another variations like `(\d+[a-zA-Z]+\d?)` and `(\d+[a-zA-Z]\d+?)` or `(\d+[a-zA-Z]+\d+?)` untill you find the one which fills your needs.

Comment: i tried a lot brother but i never get the success can you try one more for me "123 keshav A1 Keshav 111a"

Comment: @AkshayBansal what is your output for `"123 keshav A1 Keshav 111a"` ?

Comment: A1, but the ans should be applicable for all alphanumeric its means what ever input i am giving its accept like "123 akshay 1a"

Comment: @AkshayBansal for your last example, use `re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]\d)', a)`, otherwise you should put all the conditions to the regex in order to have your desired output.